# 'str' object is not callable in python class function

Tags: python, string, class

I am building a webscraper that has a `Page class`. However, I get the follwing error message when assigning the attribute `url` to the `Page class`.

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Find below my code:

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, pid, cur_id, url=None, proxy=None):
        self.pid = pid
        self.cur_id = cur_id
        if url is None:
            self.url = self._build_url()
        else:
            self.url = url
        self.content = get_page_content(self.url, proxy)
        self.crawl_date = datetime.now()

    @property
    def _build_url(self):
        my_url = root + self.pid
        return my_url
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
Full traceback:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2060, in <module>
>     main()   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2054, in main
>     globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1405, in run
>     return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community
> Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1412, in _exec
>     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>     exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "C:/single_offers.py",
> line 146, in <module>
>     main()   File "C:/single_offers.py",
> line 68, in main
>     p = Page(id, cur_id, proxy=proxy)   File "C:/single_offers.py",
> line 109, in __init__
>     self.url = self._build_url() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack trace, not just the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `_build_url` to be a *property*. As a result, you access it with just the attribute name, not by calling it:

```
self.url = self._build_url
```

Answer (score 0):

You made `_build_url` a property, so `self._build_url` gets the `str` with no call parens, but you add parens to make it `self.url = self._build_url()`. So you're trying to call the resulting string. Either remove the `@property` decorator to leave it a normal method, or remove the call parens at point of use to use the property without calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You made `_build_url` a `@property`. Because of this when you want to call this method you shouldn't use `self._build_url()`, but `self._build_url` (without the brackets).